# Match double quotes and get the contents using grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log from my server in below format, started injecting the logs to my ELK server, and got stuck in matching the log pattern.

```
2018-04-20T21:51:13.677291071-0400 level=7 [Common] [Common] [ID=22] [0001232700011fde] [00943 01248] [Thread1] "[key1:N/A key2:0 key3:N/A]: Completed flow"
```

I was able to match up to `Thread1`, how can I get the values of `key1` which is inside a double quotes.

Currently I use below pattern and store the whole message in single string.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTimestamp} level=%{NUMBER:severity} \[Common\] \[Common] \[ID=%{BASE10NUM:logId}] \[%{WORD:taskId1}] \[%{DATA:taskId2}] \[%{DATA:taskName}]%{GREEDYDATA:logString}
```

I use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to check the syntax, is there any other free utility which provides the grok patterns based on the input string?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify double quotes outside the `grok` pattern, like this,
`"\[key1:%{DATA:key1}`

This will match `key1` as well,

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTimestamp} level=%{NUMBER:severity} \[Common\] \[Common] \[ID=%{BASE10NUM:logId}] \[%{WORD:taskId1}] \[%{DATA:taskId2}] \[%{DATA:taskName}] "\[key1:%{DATA:key1}
```

The problem with above approach is that it will not match `N/A` due to forward slash. Better approach is to write a [custom pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) to escape `/` from within your `key1` value if `key` is `N/A` and also accept other character for that field,

```
"\[key1:(?<key1>(N\/A|\w+))
```

Complete pattern with `key1` would be then,

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTimestamp} level=%{NUMBER:severity} \[Common\] \[Common] \[ID=%{BASE10NUM:logId}] \[%{WORD:taskId1}] \[%{DATA:taskId2}] \[%{DATA:taskName}] "\[key1:(?<key1>(N\/A|\w+))
```

and it will produce following output,

```
{
  "logTimestamp": [
    [
      "2018-04-20T21:51:13.677291071-0400"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2018"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "04"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "20"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "21",
      "04"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "51",
      "00"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "13.677291071"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      "-0400"
    ]
  ],
  "severity": [
    [
      "7"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "7"
    ]
  ],
  "logId": [
    [
      "22"
    ]
  ],
  "taskId1": [
    [
      "0001232700011fde"
    ]
  ],
  "taskId2": [
    [
      "00943 01248"
    ]
  ],
  "taskName": [
    [
      "Thread1"
    ]
  ],
  "key1": [
    [
      "N/A"
    ]
  ]
}
```

hope this helps.